# In-App purchase - Receipt validation - Expires date wrong

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

Goodmorning everyone ! I have a little question that I would like to ask you without going to waste an incident with Apple ...

In practice I am validating the receipt of payment for an in-app purchase, specifically a one-month subscription that unlocks some features of my app.
I parse the json correctly and apparently it seems to work fine but this does not always happen! In fact it often happens that the expiration date that I go to read from the json is not correct as if the subscription was not included in the receipt and I fished only those of the day before or in any case the previous ones.
This happens in sandbox and having checked the code and reviewed well, the parse of the document I could not find a solution because often the validation of the subscription is successful. I also searched online to see if it was a common problem but I did not find a solution or a discussion. My subscription does not include trial periods.

In the specific case this morning the first test was successful, but the validation was not valid. Checking the date shown was that of the previous day and then a previous subscription made yesterday. Once the subscription to the second test expired, the subscription was successful and also validated.

Comment: can you have try some code? so provide code to see it.

Comment: Can you offer some JSOn examples as well, please?

Comment: The same thing happens to me.  I used the similar code to here: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/monetizing-your-apps-with-apples-in-app-purchases/

latest_receipt_info returns different values time to time and sometimes it does not make sense.  I hope this only happens with sandbox environment.

Comment: This is designed on purpose by the App Store for Sandbox receipts - will be normal in production. This is to make sure that you're validating correctly and not hard coding your values.